# PNG overlay over active Canvas animations

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap, overlay

I am developing a 2d sprite-based game with a bunch of animations. Developed with separate threads and in general everything is great.

I recently added a level that has a alpha PNG graphic drawn over the Canvas after the rest of the animated bitmaps have been drawn.

There is now a noticeable speed degradation on this level and it seems to sputter etc... to top it off I just added a Multiply Xfermode to the paint for the graphic and it went to a stand-still.

Is there a better way to overlay graphics in this fashion to avoid the hit in performance (I'm assuming it has to calculate the alpha channels and it apply it to the canvas bitmap)? Is there an alternative to drawing the overlay with a drawbitmap/png?

Comment: For game dev specific questions, you might get better answers at gamedev.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0):

To get better performance you could put your overlay in another window, either by using WindowManager.addView or by using a PoupWindow. The composition will then be done on the GPU.

Comment: Hmm interesting. There'd be a lot of consequences of that. Namely I'd have to have all touch events in that window since it'd be in the forefront. I may give that a try but it would require a fair amount of work. Is this something you've done?